# Oracle 12c: How can I modify an existing primary key column to an identity column?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table which contains a primary key column which is auto incremented from application. How can I modify the column to be an **identity column** in Oracle 12c?

A sample case is provided below-

```
create table tmp_identity (
   id number(100) primary key,
   value varchar2(100)
);
```

Say we populated the table with following data-

```
ID        VALUE
---------------
1         Sample 1
2         Sample 2
3         Sample 3
```

What we are planning to do is to turn this `id` column into an **identity column** which will-

- Auto increment by 1
- Start from 4

How can I do it?
If it is not possible, then is there any work-around available for this?

Comment: Does `id number(100)` column really have precision 100 ? On Oracle the precision can be from 1 to 38, and no more.

Answer (score 12):

You can't turn an existing column it into a real identity column, but you can get a similar behaviour by using a sequence as the default for the column.

```
create sequence seq_tmp_identity_id
  start with 4
  increment by 1;
```

Then use:

```
alter table tmp_identity 
   modify id 
   default seq_tmp_identity_id.nextval;
```

to make the column use the sequence as a default value. If you want you can use `default on null` to overwrite an explicit `null` value supplied during insert (this is as close as you can get to an identity column)

If you want a **real** identity column you will need to drop the current `id` column and then re-add it as an identity column:

```
alter table tmp_identity drop column id;

alter table tmp_identity 
     add id number(38) 
     generated always as identity;
```

Note that you shouldn't add the `start with 4` in this case so that all rows get a new unique number

Comment: by fix, i meant getting away from this solution

Answer (score -12):

You can rename the column from `id` to `identity` by using following query

```
ALTER TABLE tmp_identity
RENAME COLUMN id TO identity;
```

To auto increment by `1` and start from `4`, we can use sequence.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE identity_incre
MINVALUE 4
START WITH 4
INCREMENT BY 1;
```

To use the `identity_incre` sequence in your query

```
INSERT INTO suppliers
(identity, VALUE)
VALUES
(identity_incre.NEXTVAL, 'sample4');
```

Comment: Renaming a column to `identity` doesn't make it an "identity" column:

Comment: What on Earth does renaming a table have to do with an identity column?