# Auto increment item in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to make my item id auto increment, so that user cannot insert any number. I have created a sequence and a trigger.

```
create sequence t1_seq start with 1 increment by 1 nomaxvalue; 


create trigger t1_trigger
before insert on t1
for each row
   begin
     select t1_seq.nextval into :new.id from dual;
   end;
```

But, while inserting id-s, auto increment goes somenthing like: 1, 41, 52... Why it isn't going 1,2,3...

Comment: That behavior occurs when you use "GENERATED by default on null as IDENTITY". If you created your sequence manually, just set the seq.nextval as default and don't let the database manage it for you.

Answer (score 2):

First the answer. What is your "create sequence" ddl statement ? If you create a sequence with the statement

```
CREATE SEQUENCE t1_seq;
```

Then oracle will take a CACHE value of 20. Create the sequence with NOCACHE option if you want all the numbers to follow.
But... do you really need consecutive numbers ? A sequence guarantees that every number is higher than the previous one and unique. In reality you probably don't care if there are gaps, it just looks a bit off but does that matter.

That was the answer to your question. But ... if you're on 12C or higher, I suggest you use "IDENTITY COLUMNS" instead. In that case all the work is done in the background. No trigger needed, no sequence needed. Check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm) for syntax

Comment: It does matter, because they are ordinal numbers, so it has to be by some order. Don't understand why that can't be easy done in apex

Comment: Apex is just a layer on top the database. Sequences is database stuff. Create it in the database, use it in apex.

Comment: Yes I know and I did it, but still it's not working properly

Comment: What does that mean ? Still gaps ?

Comment: Please provide info. "not working properly" is not helpful. Identity columns just use normal sequences. If you want no cache then you have to excplicitly set that in the create table statement. Did you do that ? 
``` 
CREATE Table KOEN_TEST (
id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(
NOCACHE),
name VARCHAR2(10), 
PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Comment: Is is possible to modify the table that way because it's already created

Comment: Yes. Create table:

CREATE Table KOEN_TEST ( id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR2(10));
Change identity column to NOCACHE:
ALTER TABLE KOEN_TEST MODIFY id GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(NOCACHE);

Comment: error: ORA-30673: column to be modified is not an identity column

Comment: this is my create table:   CREATE TABLE  "PRIJEVOZ" 
   ( "SIFRA_PRIJEVOZA" NVARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "NAZIV_PRIJEVOZA" NVARCHAR2(25), 
  CONSTRAINT "PRIJEVOZ_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("SIFRA_PRIJEVOZA")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976743/oracle-12c-how-can-i-modify-an-existing-primary-key-column-to-an-identity-colum

Comment: I cannot drop a parent key column

Comment: Trying to prevent gaps is a waste of time. Even without the cache enabled, it's possible to use a sequence value and then do a rollback. Why do you think you need to avoid gaps? What is the business case?

Comment: Because it is for ordinal numbers of invoice items

Comment: You have an answer to the original question. Now test, try with examples, read documentation. When you get stuck, feel free to post a new question with as much details as possible. It's not productive to try to ask followup questions in the comments.

Comment: Mateja, I was thinking about this a bit more. You never mentioned that this was for invoice numbers that cannot have gaps. I would ask the question again describing the exact business case. Sequences is probably not the right solution because they cannot guarantee no gaps. If someone take .NEXTVAL and the transaction is rolled back, that value is gone.