# Oracle 19.17 Reference a sequence as default of Primary Key column fails with ORA 02262

Tags: oracle, sequence, identity

This command used with an existing table and sequence fails with ORA 02262 Error Occurs while type checking column default expression

```
MESSAGES TABLE INFO
ID NUMBER(38) Primary Key

ALTER TABLE MESSAGES MODIFY
ID DEFAULT MESSAGES.SEQ.NEXTVAL
```

However I can do this

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TEST_SEQ;

CREATE TABLE TEST
(ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR2)
```

and then

```
ALTER TABLE TEST MODIFY
(ID DEFAULT TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL
```

and it will work.

The main objective is to move away from using the combination of sequences and triggers to assist with populating IDs and move toward a closer concept of an IDENTITY as stated here

[Oracle 12c: How can I modify an existing primary key column to an identity column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976743/oracle-12c-how-can-i-modify-an-existing-primary-key-column-to-an-identity-colum)

1. I dont believe there is a type checking issue since the sequence should return a NUMERIC value which is going into a column type that is NUMERIC?
2. Grants should be ok since insert data into messages table using the "old way" with sequences and triggers.

---

```
ALTER TABLE MESSAGES MODIFY
ID DEFAULT MESSAGES.SEQ.NEXTVAL
```

However I can do this

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TEST_SEQ;

CREATE TABLE TEST
(ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR2)
```

and then

```
ALTER TABLE TEST MODIFY
(ID DEFAULT TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL
```

and it will work.

Comment: In your first statement your sequence name is invalid (unless y.ou have another schema called MESSAGES which has granted privs on its sequence SEQ to your table owner) So maybe the problem is just that you're trying with the wrong sequence name. Best thing to do is post CREATE TABLE and CREATE SEQUENCE commands which then allow the reproduction of the ORA-02622 error.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but I don't quite understand what you are trying to say.

Title suggests that you use Oracle 19. It supports identity columns, so - why don't you then use that functionality? Note that Oracle will create a sequence in the background, so if you thought that you'd get rid of a sequence - nope, you won't. But you won't have to use a trigger, that's correct.

```
SQL> create table messages (id number generated always as identity primary key);

Table created.
```

---

If you do it *your way*, why do you think it should work at all?

```
SQL> create table messages (id number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> alter table messages modify id default MESSAGES.SEQ.NEXTVAL;
alter table messages modify id default MESSAGES.SEQ.NEXTVAL
                            *          ====================
ERROR at line 1:                       what does this represent?        
ORA-02262: ORA-2289 occurs while type-checking column default value expression
```

A sequence must **exist** before using it as default value; I don't think that Oracle will create one for you that way:

```
SQL> create sequence seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> alter table messages modify id default SEQ.NEXTVAL;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Therefore, from my point of view, everything works **as expected**. If I'm wrong, please, explain why do you think I'm wrong and - if possible - provide documentation that suggest different.

Comment: Thanks.  First, our internet is completely isolated from the application/database infrastructure so I cannot directly copy code.  Second, this is an existing production system with data in the 1TB range.  Its also an old application that has existed since 2008 and gone through upgrades over the years to be at Oracle 19.  Objective, to minimize the impact on production, is to get rid of the triggers and just use the sequences by using the "DEFAULT" option of the column definition.  Thus, the reason for ALTER.   

Below link also describes issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976743/

Comment: Adding ...  not stated in my example above is that MESSAGES_SEQ already exists and part of legacy structure.

Comment: Then it was you who did it wrong. If - as your previous comment says - sequence MESSAGES_SEQ (with an underline) exists, why did you alter table specifying DEFAULT MESSAGES.SEQ.NEXTVAL (with a dot)? If you used DEFAULT MESSAGES_SEQ.NEXTVAL, everything would (should) have been fine.

Comment: Yes, I did make a typo, MESSAGES_SEQ not MESSAGE_SEQ.  Resolved